# Java Array Size fixed

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

in `Java` I want to create an `array` with a fixed size, so I can add new Elements and the first Element drops out.

For example:

The `array` with the size of `5`: `{1,2,3,4,5}` then I add "`6`" and the "`1`" drops out so I have `{2,3,4,5,6}`, the I add "`7`" and the "`2`" drops out: `{3,4,5,6,7}` ...

So I want to add a new Element and remove the first Element. Is there an easy way to do it or do I have to implement it myself?

Can I do this with an `ArrayList` and just remove the first `Object`? 
If I remove the first `Object` of an `ArrayList`, will the second Object automatically become the first object?

Thanks

Comment: The keyword for that is "circular array", I'm sure you can find a Java implementation.

Comment: Not sure about array question but for arraylist yes if you remove element at 0th index in array list element at 1st index will come to 0th index.

Comment: *"or do I have to implement it myself"* Of course you do. There is no "adding" in arrays, only "replacing". You replace the item on a certain index with another one.

Comment: Instead of asking "can I do this with an `ArrayList`" just try it yourself. It's downright stupid to ask something like that here.

Comment: Thanks, circular array was the word I was looking for. I will take a look at.

Comment: Beware of the downvotes guys, *at least explain why you are downvoting*. This is extremely rude behavior. I don't think this question is that bad. I certainly would not have come up with `EvictingQueue` as answer just by a single google search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you don't need necessarily a `List`, you could use an [`EvictingQueue`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/EvictingQueue.html) from **Google Guava** which is a non-blocking queue that **automatically evicts elements from the head** of the queue when attempting to add new elements onto the queue and it is full.

```
// Create an EvictingQueue with a max size of 5
Collection<Integer> collection = EvictingQueue.create(5);
// Add 5 elements to the queue
collection.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
System.out.println(collection);
// Add one more element
collection.add(6);
System.out.println(collection);
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: I would not go all the way back to collection when creating an `EvictingQueue`. Instead I'd use at least a `Queue` reverence.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I wanted more to show how it works, the fact that it is a `Queue`doesn't really matter in this context but I agree with you, it is up to the OP now.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes yes I know, I already did, the more I spend time on this website the less I understand the downvotes

Answer (score -1):

just set the ith element to the ith+1 element and add the thing you want at the end:

```java
static int[] g(int arr[],int n){
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++){
        arr[i]=arr[i+1];
    }
    arr[arr.length-1] = n;
    return arr;
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
    int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(g(arr,6)));
}
```

output:

`[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Comment: Please try and keep to Java coding rules. These are examples which should be easy to read. Explain what you're doing with inline comments and name your variables. The first thing I thought when I saw this was g(ee), what's this?

Comment: There isn't much to explain, what your asking for is to explain what a `for loop` does in java. But if it helps... take for example the `0th` element (`arr[0]`) and set it equal to the  `ith+1` element (`arr[0+1] = arr[1]`) so `arr` would then look like `[2,2,3,4,5]`. Continuing to do the above procedure while `i < arr.length - 1` gives you `[2, 3, 4, 5, 5]`. Now simply "add the thing you want at the end" or take the element at `arr[arr.length - 1]` and set it equal to "the thing you want" (in my example I have `6`) so `arr[arr.length - 1] = 6` or `arr[4] = 6`.

Answer (score -1):

You might have to do something like:

```
public class Num {

    int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5};

    public void add(int number){
        int[] temp = array;
        array = new int[array.length];

        for(int i=1;i<temp.length;i++){
            array[i-1] = temp[i];
        }

        array[array.length-1] = number;

        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            System.out.print(array[i]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Num num = new Num();
        num.add(6);
        num.add(7);
        num.add(8);
    }
}
```

and output would look like this:

> 2 3 4 5 6
>   3 4 5 6 7
>   4 5 6 7 8